# Calculate the remaining overtime hours to be paid

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a MS-SQL Report that seems quite complicated.

In the company there is a rule which says that overtime hours that people made should be paid automatically after 30 days (at the following payroll) if the employees doesn't take those hours as free time off.

The report must contain a list with the remaining overtime hours to be paid at the next payroll.

The calculation will consume the oldest hours to the newest.

This is the list with the Overtime Hours of the employees (there is only one employee for the sake of the example)

```
person_ID   OvertimeHourDate    OVTHoursMade
123123      15.02.2017          2
123123      17.02.2017          4
123123      19.02.2017          2
123123      21.02.2017          2
123123      23.02.2017          5
123123      25.02.2017          5
123123      28.02.2017          7
123123      15.03.2017          7
123123      17.03.2017          8
123123      21.03.2017          6
123123      23.03.2017          8
123123      25.03.2017          5
123123      27.03.2017          8
123123      29.03.2017          6
```

For example, if no free time is taken off by this employee, the 2h from 15.02.2017 will be automatically paid 30 days later (more exactly on the immediately following payroll 31.03.2017); the same for the next line.

This is the list with the free time off taken.

```
person_ID   Date        Hours Off Taken
158223      22.02.2017      8
158223      24.02.2017      7
```

The 8h hours will be substracted from the first 3 lines (the oldest dates): 2+4+2

```
person_ID   OvertimeHourDate    OVTHoursMade
123123      15.02.2017          2
123123      17.02.2017          4
123123      19.02.2017          2
```

The 7 hours are calculated from the next following lines: 2+5

```
person_ID   OvertimeHourDate    OVTHoursMade
123123      21.02.2017          2
123123      23.02.2017          5
```

And the final report should look like this

```
person_ID   Overtime Hours Remaining To Be Paid Until Next Payroll on 31.03.2017
158223                        12
```

So the 12 hours have been calculated like this:
Since the hours before the following dates have been consumed, we will take in account only these:

```
25.02.2017 5h
28.02.2017 7h
```

The days after that are not taken in account because the date exceeds the current payroll and they will be paid on the next payroll (31.04.2017)

It seems quite complicated and I would really need you advice.

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: 1) On payroll date, 2) For each employee 3) calculate overtime hours taken more than 30 days ago 4) for which no time in lieu has been taken 5) and for which no overtime payment has been made previously

Comment: Q1: Does time in lieu have to be taken after the overtime? Or can it be before? If before, does it have to be in the current payroll period?
Q2: What is the rule if time in lieu exceeds overtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it day by day, then you can union the days of and overtime like this, look at the "total" CTE, which takes the personid, date and overtime hours and unions with the personid, date and negative off hours.

```
set dateformat  DMY
;with overtime as
(
select
*
from
(
values

(123123, cast('15.02.2017' as date),2)
,(123123,cast('17.02.2017' as date),4)
,(123123,cast('19.02.2017' as date),2)
,(123123,cast('21.02.2017' as date),2)
,(123123,cast('23.02.2017' as date),5)
,(123123,cast('25.02.2017' as date),5)
,(123123,cast('28.02.2017' as date),7)
,(123123,cast('15.03.2017' as date),7)
,(123123,cast('17.03.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('21.03.2017' as date),6)
,(123123,cast('23.03.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('25.03.2017' as date),5)
,(123123,cast('27.03.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('29.03.2017' as date),6)

) a(person_ID,   OvertimeHourDate ,   OVTHoursMade))
,hoursoff as
(
select * from
(values

(123123,cast('22.02.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('24.02.2017' as date),7)
) b(person_ID,   Date,        [Hours Off Taken]))


,total as
(
select person_ID,eomonth(OvertimeHourDate,1) eom,OvertimeHourDate [Date],OVTHoursMade [Hours] from overtime
union all
select person_ID,eomonth([date],1),[date],-[Hours Off Taken]
from hoursoff
)
select * from total
```

This gives:

```
person_ID   eom Date    Hours
123123  31-03-2017  15-02-2017  2
123123  31-03-2017  17-02-2017  4
123123  31-03-2017  19-02-2017  2
123123  31-03-2017  21-02-2017  2
123123  31-03-2017  23-02-2017  5
123123  31-03-2017  25-02-2017  5
123123  31-03-2017  28-02-2017  7
123123  30-04-2017  15-03-2017  7
123123  30-04-2017  17-03-2017  8
123123  30-04-2017  21-03-2017  6
123123  30-04-2017  23-03-2017  8
123123  30-04-2017  25-03-2017  5
123123  30-04-2017  27-03-2017  8
123123  30-04-2017  29-03-2017  6
123123  31-03-2017  22-02-2017  -8
123123  31-03-2017  24-02-2017  -7
```

The "EOM" column is the date for when the wage is to be paid out.

Now, we use two analytical function, sum, and rownumber:

In stead of the las "select * from total" use this:

```
select 
    person_ID
    ,eom
    ,Date
    ,Hours
    ,sum(Hours) over (partition by person_ID,eom order by date) TotHours
    ,row_number() over (partition by person_ID,eom order by date desc) rn
from total
order by date
```

This gives us a running total of the hours, and the rn column gives a descending count of entries each month, so that the last one has rn=1

```
person_ID   eom Date    Hours   TotHours    rn
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-15  2   2   9
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-17  4   6   8
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-19  2   8   7
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-21  2   10  6
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-22  -8  2   5
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-23  5   7   4
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-24  -7  0   3
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-25  5   5   2
123123  2017-03-31  2017-02-28  7   12  1
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-15  7   7   7
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-17  8   15  6
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-21  6   21  5
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-23  8   29  4
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-25  5   34  3
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-27  8   42  2
123123  2017-04-30  2017-03-29  6   48  1
```

The number of overtime hours pr employee pr wage is found by:

```
set dateformat  DMY
;with overtime as
(
select
*
from
(
values

(123123, cast('15.02.2017' as date),2)
,(123123,cast('17.02.2017' as date),4)
,(123123,cast('19.02.2017' as date),2)
,(123123,cast('21.02.2017' as date),2)
,(123123,cast('23.02.2017' as date),5)
,(123123,cast('25.02.2017' as date),5)
,(123123,cast('28.02.2017' as date),7)
,(123123,cast('15.03.2017' as date),7)
,(123123,cast('17.03.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('21.03.2017' as date),6)
,(123123,cast('23.03.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('25.03.2017' as date),5)
,(123123,cast('27.03.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('29.03.2017' as date),6)

) a(person_ID,   OvertimeHourDate ,   OVTHoursMade))
,hoursoff as
(
select * from
(values

(123123,cast('22.02.2017' as date),8)
,(123123,cast('24.02.2017' as date),7)
) b(person_ID,   Date,        [Hours Off Taken]))


,total as
(
select person_ID,eomonth(OvertimeHourDate,1) eom,OvertimeHourDate [Date],OVTHoursMade [Hours] from overtime
union all
select person_ID,eomonth([date],1),[date],-[Hours Off Taken]
from hoursoff
)
select person_id,eom,TotHours 
from
(
select 
    person_ID
    ,eom
    ,Date
    ,Hours
    ,sum(Hours) over (partition by person_ID,eom order by date) TotHours
    ,row_number() over (partition by person_ID,eom order by date desc) rn
from total
) a
where rn=1
```